# Sending sms in android

Tags: android

When I use the following code:

```
String phoneNumber="0527276513";

Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumber.toString());

Intent smsSIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);

String smsBody="hii";

smsSIntent.putExtra("sms_body", smsBody.toString());

startActivity(smsSIntent);
```

The code opens the default application for sending SMS in my phone with the SMS body but the message doesn't get sent.

How do I send an SMS dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. Before making any changes please update your manifest by adding the following line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

And in your method/function use the following code:

```
String phoneNumber = "myphonenumber";
String message = "mymessage";

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that on Android 4.4 (KitKat) and higher devices, only the default SMS app can send text messages, per the [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html).

Assuming your app is not a full fledged SMS replacement app, the approach you have outlined is the correct one to ensure your app works on all Android versions.